# HTTP status 404 while calling ajax url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, thymeleaf

I have a form which has submit button and button. I am implementing an ajax cal for a button using get method. I have passed value in url. and while clicking on button, it is making an ajax cal. but in the middle before success function, stopping abruptly. If I see in "Show Command Line Popup" in mozilla, I am able to see the error status:404."The requested resource is not available".

I am using thymeleaf and spring mvc. below is my ajax cal

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function process(){
        alert("button clicked");
        $.ajax({
            url:'searchabc',
        }).done(function (){
            alert("success");
        });
    }
</script
```

and spring method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "xxx/yyy/searchabc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String searchabc(Model model){
        log.debug("hello");
         return "helloworld";
    }
```

Comment: what is `searchabc`

Comment: thats the url name. I have just given for testing purpose.

Comment: pass data model as well to match the signature

Comment: That is what I missed. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
        url:'./searchabc',
```

To:

```
        url:'searchabc',
```

Comment: Try making some tests using postman, maybe this route is not configurated correctly

Comment: I have never worked on postman. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Try navigate to this url using your browser

Comment: getting http status 404. and the url refers to request mapping right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128283/discussion-between-swetha-and-cleiton).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add `@ResponseBody`. Please also validate the url. Also it will be useful if you share the url mapping from application context and web.xml

```
@RequestMapping(value = "xxx/yyy/searchabc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String searchabc(Model model){
        log.debug("hello");
         return "helloworld";
    }
```